# Job recommendations over-extrapolation: I apply to one remote job based in Germany

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

### ...and now I have German citizenship.

[image]

Any way we can refine the job recommendation system to be more aware of location/language/background?

The vast majority of the jobs I've applied to through Stack Overflow are located in the United States and I've never worked in any countries besides the United States.  Now *all* of my recommendations are for Germany.

**Edit**: Two months later, 100% of the jobs recommended on my profile are in Germany:

[image]

At least now they're in English.

Comment: Since you're obviously German, perhaps you should take this to https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/de/talent :-)

Comment: Well, at least one of them is offering Visa Sponsorship, so they know you're not German. And as an AI developer, I have to side with the AI here. If you've applied repeatedly in the USA, that's clearly not working out for you. :X

Comment: Damn, if I knew it was that easy I'd have done it back on 24th June 2016 (Brexit joke for those wondering the importance of the date). :)

Comment: IMO there should be a choice for the companies to specify which citizenship is required by them for this job and an option for users to specify their citizenship. So that irrelevant jobs are not shown to the users. I get a lot of jobs which provides remote work, but require you to have USA citizenship (which I don't have). It's pretty confusing for us who are not from USA or EU.

Comment: Maybe it's fate :)

Answer (score 3):

I see that [in your job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) you have Germany as one of your work locations.

Please remove that and it should stop recommending you Germany based jobs :)

Comment: I swear I didn't put that there.  Maybe it's my fault after all. 

Comment: @brandaemon hmm... we don't update people's preferences (at least, voluntarily :P) so if you see them changing, please report it so that we can take a look. Also, if the recommendations are... bad, please also let us know :)